# Washing bacteria out with water

Tags: bacteriology

When I wash my running shoes by my hands,
I leave them near the window to dry them quickly.

Although they got sunlight in daytime and well dried after I came back from work, I could feel bad smell from them.

The smell was worse than when it was not washed for long time.

So I guess that the water increases the number of bad bacteria on shoes.

My conclusion is that water should be used to wash dirty things out only for a short time and
it should be dried as soon as possible.

Although our body is alive and can resist against bad bacteria on our skin which get nutrition from water, it seems that water should be used for a short time.

Am I right? Please advise on my thinking.
Thanks.

Comment: I think that "bad bacteria" isn't the right term to use here. Maybe mold is more accurate? What do you mean by "use water for a short time"? Do you mean dry out quickly?

Comment: It means washing with water for a short time, and we should dry out quickly as well, if water is helpful for 'the bad bacteria'. I had thought water was always helpful for removing smells in the past.